# What is the way to go from point 1 to 2 while remaining in the region defined by half torus?

Tags: optimization, mathematical-modeling, math-software, path-connected, spherical-trigonometry

Basically this is a trajectory planning problem. As shown in figure below, how can I ensure that in moving from a point (x,y,z) to another point within torus, I don't get out of that torus region?

[go from (1) to (2) and from (2) to (3) without getting out of torus region](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnVUr.jpg)

Comment: Parameterize the space outside z-axis by cylindrical coordinate system: 
$(\rho,\theta, z) \mapsto (\rho\cos\theta,\rho\sin\theta,z)$. In this coordinate system, the torus becomes a cylinder $(\rho - R)^2 + (z-z_0)^2 = r^2$ where $R$ and $r$ are the major/minor radius of the torus. For any two points inside the cylinder, you can join them by a straight line (in $\rho\theta z$-space) which lies completely inside the cylinder. When you map this straight line back into $xyz$-space, you get a path that contains the two points and lies completely inside the torus.